# Node Js return null from mongoose collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I create one application in node JS where i fetch data from mongoose database as below

```
await dataCollection.find({
  type: 'user',
}).sort([['short_order', 1]]).then((results) => {
  console.log(reslts)
});
```

Which return data from mongodb but sometimes it's return null without any changes (return null from 2-3 request of total 10)
Also use apollo server for graphql query where receive below collection data.
Please suggest how can i resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

there is a typo, you should be aware of: `console.log(reslts)` which is `results`.